# Issue when trying to hide Action Bar with shared code

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript, angular7

I've build an Angular + nativescript app. I'm trying to hide the action bar (like a lot of people).

I've made two service helpers. Both have same signature. One is for web and the other is for mobile. For the mobile helper, I deal with the TNS Page component which I inject.

But when I run mobile app, the action bar is always here.

## Helpers

**action-bar-helper.service.tns.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page/page";
@Injectable()
export class ActionBarHelperService {  
    constructor(private page: Page){

    }

    hideActionBar(){
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
}
```

**action-bar-helper.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export  class ActionBarHelperService {    
    constructor(){}
    hideActionBar(){}
}
```

## Shared component for mobile and web

**login.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent{

  constructor(private actionBarHelperService: ActionBarHelperService) 
  {
    this.actionBarHelperService.hideActionBar();
  }
}
```

In addition, I've set createFrameOnBootstrap to true in **main.tns.ts**:

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from 'nativescript-angular/platform';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformNativeScriptDynamic({ createFrameOnBootstrap: true }).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I don't know if that help, but when I run my emulator and I do not set this to true, I've an error which says than page is null:

```
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.docdoc on device emulator-5554.
JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'actionBarHidden' of null
JS: ERROR CONTEXT {
JS:   "view": {
JS:     "def": {
JS:       "nodeFlags": 33669121,
JS:       "rootNodeFlags": 33554433,
JS:       "nodeMatchedQueries": 0,
JS:       "flags": 0,
JS:       "nodes": [
JS:         {
JS:           "nodeIndex": 0,
JS:           "parent": null,
JS:           "renderParent": null,
JS:           "bindingIndex": 0,
JS:           "outputIndex": 0,
JS:           "checkIndex": 0,
JS:           "flags": 33554433,
JS:           "childFlags": 114688,
JS:           "directChildFlags": 114688,
JS:           "childMatchedQueries": 0,
JS:           "matchedQueries": {},
JS:           "matchedQueryIds": 0,
JS:           "references": {},
JS:           "ngContentIndex": null,
JS:           "childCount": 1,
JS:           "bindings": [],
JS:           "bindingFlags": 0,
JS:           "outputs": [],
JS:           "element": {
JS:             "ns": "",
JS:             "name": "app-login",
JS:             "attrs": [],
JS:             "template": null,
JS:             "componentProvider": {
JS:               "nodeIndex": 1,
JS:               "parent": "[Circular]",
JS:               "renderParent": "[Circular]",
JS:               "bindingIndex":...
```

Any ideas or solutions?

## SOLUTION:

Thanks to @Manoj, I've write a directive. See below:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/page/page';

@Directive({
  selector: '[hideActionBar]'
})
export class HideActionBarDirective {
  constructor(private page: Page) {
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
  }
}
```

and now in my **login.component.tns.html**:

```
<StackLayout hideActionBar>
    <Button text="login works!" class="btn btn-primary"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ActionBarHelperService` is a dependency for `LoginComponent`, the service must be instantiated even before the page was created.

May be you could pass the page as an argument to `hideActionBar` method Or simply set the `visibility` attribute on `ActionBar` tag in `login.component.html` Or use a directive instead of service.

Comment: As mentionned to Narendra Mongiya, I've already try to pass the page as an argument. For the second way, I haven't an ActionBar tag in my login.component.tns.html because ActionBar is set by default under Android. However, your solution with directive seems to be interesting... May resolve the issue. I will try. Thank you

Comment: Your solution works great. I hadn't thought of it, but directive are a simple and clean solution. It even makes more sense than services to interact with the template. See above my edit question

Answer (score 1):

ActionBarHelperService is expecting a argument(page) in Constructor(

`constructor(private page: Page)`

)  but when you are creating an instance of it in login.component.ts by doing the following way no aruguments is getting passed in ActionBarHelperService

`constructor(private actionBarHelperService: ActionBarHelperService)`

Comment: Actually, I've already trying to do this but since my login component is shared, when I run `ng serve`, angular cli says it can't resolve dependency Page from "tns-core-modules/ui/page/page" while this dependency is in nodes_modules folder... However, `tns run android ` works well in this case and the Action Bar is hidden.